# Method Overriding using super keyword

Tags: java, super, overriding

I have one doubt, Please see the following code. i have three classes `A`,`B` and `InheritanceExample`. Here I am calling the `super.run()` from the main class; it is calling the `B` class `run()` method.

Is there any option to call `A` class run method from the main class (`InheritanceExample`) with out creating an instance for class A?

```
class A
{
    void run()
    {
        System.out.println("<<<====Class A run Method===>>>>");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    void run()
    {

        System.out.println("<<<====Class B run Method===>>>>");
        super.run();
    }
}

public class InheritanceExample extends B{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    void run()
    {
        System.out.println("<<<====Main Class run Method===>>>>");
        super.run();
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InheritanceExample a = new InheritanceExample();
    a.run();
} 
    }
```

Comment: The question is do you want to create an *instance* of `A` when you create an *instance* of `InheritanceExample`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `B` *extends* `A` and `InheritanceExample` *extends* `B` you are creating an instance. Make method `A.run()` *static*.

```
class A
{
    void static run()
    {
        System.out.println("<<<====Class A run Method===>>>>");
    }
}

class B
{
    void run()
    {
        System.out.println("<<<====Class B run Method===>>>>");
        A.run();
    }
}

public class InheritanceExample extends B {

    @Override
    void run()
    {
        System.out.println("<<<====Main Class run Method===>>>>");
        super.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InheritanceExample a = new InheritanceExample();
        a.run();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Not without making A.run() different from B.run(), such as by making A.run() static.

When B extends A, you as a programmer must ensure that from the callers perspective B "is-a" A. What you want to do is to break this rule.

If you want to use a B as an A, you are probably trying to do something at the calling point, that should be handled internally in B.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve. But looking at the class hierarchy and structure, it is not possible to directly call run method of Class A. But if we change and introduce a additional static method say runImpl in Class A, and call same method from run method of Class A. Now we can call runImpl from anywhere as it is static and run method too internally is calling runImpl so same implementation is getting call via run and runImpl.

Below is the code snippet:

```
class A
{
    void run()
    {   
        runImpl();
    }

    public static void runImpl(){
        System.out.println("<<<====Class A run Method===>>>>");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    void run()
    {

        System.out.println("<<<====Class B run Method===>>>>");
        super.run();
    }   

}

public class InheritanceExample extends B{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    void run()
    {
        System.out.println("<<<====Main Class run Method===>>>>");
        super.run();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.runImpl();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use `B.runImpl()` or `InheritanceExample.runImpl()`.

Comment: Since, Class B is extending Class A and InheritanceExample is extending Class B, Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I should have said *it is also* since it wasn't a question rather an observation.

Comment: Ok, Java doesn't allow skipping the hierarchy. So since Class InheritanceExample is extending Class B which is extending A, their is no way one can call instance method run of class A without creating instance of Class A from Class InheritanceExample as it is not the direct subclass to Class A. Only way to call method without creating instance is declaring it static and since we are declaring it static and Class A is super class it is also getting exposed via sub classes.

Comment: I know I wasn't arguing with you,I think OP wants `InheritanceExample` class to contain `A` class `run` method functionality without the need of creating an *instance* of class `A`. So *skipping hierachy* is something you do by removing `A` from hierachy. The only thing left it's OP say what he actually wants. You can see an example in my answer. BTW I like your answer.

Comment: hey, I am not taking this as an argument, but as a discussion. And idea was to provide more explanation to the other readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class a{

      void run(){

          System.out.println("runing method run of a clss");

      }
  }
  class b extends a{
      void run(){
          super.run();
          System.out.println("runing method run of b clss");
      }

  }
  class InheritanceExample extends b{
      void run(){
          super.run();
          System.out.println("running method run in inheritance class");
      }
  }

  class pratics{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("********");
        InheritanceExample a1=new InheritanceExample();
        a1.run();
       System.out.println("********");
      }
  }
```

Comment: In inheritance whenever u want to call super class you have to use super keyword.....